# Required DataAnnotations needs BeginForm to fire validation in MVC5

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it necessary to write and place all controls inside

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())    
{
    // HTML Elements and HTML Helpers.
}
```

while using [Required] DataAnnotations ?

I am facing strange issue in MVC5 based application. The problem is that I have used one property named e.g "Credit" in model and the datatype of this property is integer and set[Required] DataAnnotations above that property.

But I haven't used Begin form. So in this case validation doesn't fire. whereas If I write BeginForm then validation works.

So, Is it necessary to place all html elements & html helpers inside BeginForm to validate controls ?

Thanks 
-Nimesh.

Comment: If you want client side validation, then yes in needs to be inside `<form>` tags. But what would be the point of including a form control outside `<form>` tags?

Comment: Thanks.. I got it. I just wanted to make sure that we must mentioned BeginForm  to fire validation ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the client-side validation to work, then yes the form controls etc. need to be within a `<form>` tag (as generated by the HTML.BeginForm helper). Server-side validation would still work regardless of this.

Like the commenter above, I would question why you want to have controls outside a form tag in the first place. Even if you plan to submit the data back using Ajax, it's better semantic design to use a form tag, because it's clear which data items belong together, and it also makes it much easier to gather the data to submit via ajax (e.g. if you have jQuery, you can use `$("#myForm").serialize()` to automatically collect the values from all the controls within a form and pass that to the ajax request).

Comment: _Server-side validation would still work regardless of this_ is not strictly correct. If the property is `int`, and no value is posted, then it will be `0` which is valid despite the fact its not the correct value

Comment: @StephenMuecke true in that specific case. It's up to the developer to decide whether they want to tolerate that or do something custom. But my general point was that server side validation will still take place. We should never assume that client side validation is going to happen - it can always be bypassed by someone determined enough, so the developer should ensure that the server side validation is adequate, regardless of the status of the client side code.

Comment: You may not have understood my comment. If the control is outside the form and the user enters "ABC" in the textbox (an invalid value for `int`) no server side validation will be performed for the property because no value is posted for the property - its just initialized to `0`. So to say _server-side validation would still work regardless of this_ (and _server side validation will still take place_) is misleading as a general statement.

Comment: @StephenMuecke if you collect the value via javascript and submit the data via Ajax then it would be validated on the server. You don't technically need a form in order to to that

Comment: Sure, but there is no mention of javascript/ajax in the question :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke true but if he's asking whether he can validate his data without using a form, then presumably he had some other way of submitting it in mind

Answer (score 1):

We need to validate something when we post some data to the server, right. And for posting some data to the server you will need form tag, whether you use `BeginForm()` or the `<form>` tag. You need tags inside the form those will be  validated by the server.

I guess, this will give the answer to your question. Enjoy!